# Type signature of parser with existential quantification

Tags: parsing, haskell, types, existential-type

In the beginning I had this simple type for a parser:

```
data Parser a = Parser ([Token] -> Either String (a, [Token]))
```

I use the Either for error messages on the left side and the parsed expression with the rest of the tokens on the right side.

This function "unpacks" the parser function.

```
parse :: Parser a -> [Token] -> Either String (a, [Token])
parse (Parser p) = p
```

My goal was to make the Parser more general that it does not only take tokens as input. So I used the ExistentialQuantification pragma and changed it to:

```
data Parser a = forall b. ([b] -> Either String (a, [b]))
```

What I want to know is: *What type does the function "parse" have now?*

I could not figure it out and it cannot be inferred. GHCi gave this error:

```
Couldn't match type `t' with `[b] -> Either String (t1, [b])'
  `t' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the inferred type of parse :: Parser t1 -> t
    at ParserCombinator.hs:9:1
In the expression: p
In an equation for `parse': parse (Parser p) = p
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
Thanks a lot for your answers.

The reason I wanted the type to look like "Parser a" because I had seen this in other parsing libraries for example in parsec.
But I saw now that this is just a shorthand for parsers that take strings as input.

It makes sense to use "data Parser b a" It was something I also tried earlier, but then I had a strange error in the monad instance for my parser, because I wrote data Parser a b instead:

```
import Control.Monad.Error

data Parser a b = Parser ([b] -> Either String (a, [b]))
parse (Parser p) = p

instance Monad (Parser x) where
    p >>= f = Parser (\tokens -> do
        (parsed, rest) <- parse p tokens 
        parse (f parsed) rest)
    return a = Parser (\ts -> Right (a, ts))
    fail b     = Parser (\_ -> Left b)
```

It gives this error:

```
ParserCombinator.hs:12:18:
    Couldn't match type `x' with `b'
      `x' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at ParserCombinator.hs:9:24
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            >>= :: Parser x a -> (a -> Parser x b) -> Parser x b
          at ParserCombinator.hs:10:5
    Expected type: a
      Actual type: x
    In the first argument of `f', namely `parsed'
    In the first argument of `parse', namely `(f parsed)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: parse (f parsed) rest

ParserCombinator.hs:12:26:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `b'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            >>= :: Parser x a -> (a -> Parser x b) -> Parser x b
          at ParserCombinator.hs:10:5
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            >>= :: Parser x a -> (a -> Parser x b) -> Parser x b
          at ParserCombinator.hs:10:5
    Expected type: [b]
      Actual type: [a]
    In the second argument of `parse', namely `rest'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: parse (f parsed) rest

ParserCombinator.hs:13:38:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `x'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for return :: a -> Parser x a
          at ParserCombinator.hs:13:5
      `x' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at ParserCombinator.hs:9:24
    In the expression: a
    In the first argument of `Right', namely `(a, ts)'
    In the expression: Right (a, ts)
```

Why does it work if you use Parser b a instead of Parser a b? And why do I need this x in Parser x? What does it contain?
It would be nice if you could give an example for another monad instance where this variable is used.

Comment: I think you'll find that you _cannot_ write the `parse` function any more. It will be ill-typed. Probably the simplest thing to do is just add the token type to the `Parser` type.

Comment: 'x' is the type variable introduced in 'instance Monad (Parser x)'

Answer (score 9):

You mean

```
data Parser a = forall b. Parser ([b] -> Either String (a, [b]))
```

What this actually means becomes clearer if you write the existential in its more rigourous GADT notation:

```
data Parser a where
  Parser :: forall b. ([b] -> Either String (a, [b])) -> Parser a
```

i.e. the constructor `Parser` is a universally-quantified function taking a `([b] -> ...` parser, but returning always a `Parser a` that knows nothing about what specific `b` is to be used within. Therefore, this is basically useless: you can't supply a list of `b` token if you don't know what type that is actually supposed to be!

To make it concrete: `parse` would be the inverse of `Parser`; that swaps the quantors so it'd be an existential (duh) function

```
parse :: exists b . Parser a -> ([b] -> Either String (a, [b]))
```

Now, such a type doesn't exist in Haskell, but it's equivalent to having the arguments universal:

```
parse :: Parser a -> ((forall b . [b]) -> Either String (a, exists b . [b]))
```

At this point it's clear you can't use this in any meaningful way: the only inhabitants of `forall b. [b]` are `[]` and `undefined` (and, as Tikhon Jelvis remarks, `[undefined]`, `[undefined, undefined]`, `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` etc.).

---

I'm not sure what you actually intend to do with this type, but an existential is definitely not the right approach. Probably you should do

```
data Parser b a = Parser ([b] -> Either String (a, [b]))
```

Comment: To be a bit of a pedant, you could also have `[undefined]`, `[undefined, undefined]` and so on ;).

Comment: @Tikhon 'forall b. [b]' is an unusual representation for the natural numbers.

Comment: @Cirdec: Haha, yes. The two are actually deeply related: lists are basically just natural numbers with stuff attached. (`Succ` and `Zero` vs `Cons` and `Nil`) If we promise to ignore the stuff, we just get natural numbers again :).

Comment: @Cirdec: what's `undefined` then, though – infinity or what? When you include bottom, the number-set isomorphies become rather more awkward. I'd stick to saying "`[()]` is an unusual representation for the natural numbers".